# What's the purpose of scope resolution operator when using ios_base in C++

Tags: c++, class, scope, resolution, operator-keyword

the following example is from Bjarne's book -
" Programming and principles using C++" , The example:

```
fstream fs;
fs.open("foo",ios_base::in);
fs.close();
fs.open("foo",ios_base::out);
```

I understand that I use scope resolution operator for namespaces , when using enumerations , when there's a class inside a class, but What I don't understand is , what is the purpose of the scope resolution operator while using the `ios_base::in` and `ios_base::out`?

Comment: To resolve scope, probably...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A general way to view the scope resolution operator is to say that you use it for resolving things that can be resolved statically. This includes the things that you listed in the question, but other things should be included as well.

Most notably, your list does not include static members of a class. This is precisely what `in` and `out` are - they are [static data members](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode), so you need scope resolution operator to resolve them. The applicability is not limited to static data members: static member functions are also resolved using the scope resolution operator.

Answer (score 7):

> What is the purpose of the scope resolution operator while using the `ios_base::in` and `ios_base::out`?

**The purpose is to, um, *resolve scope*.**

It's to specify that the symbols `in` and `out` in this context are inside the scope `[std::]ios_base`.

Otherwise, your compiler would not have the faintest clue which `in` and `out` you are talking about.

Specifically, in this case, they are static members of the class `std::ios_base`.

Comment: I have did this : https://ideone.com/d3RYsk  , I included that i'm using namespace std , but I canno't use scope resolution operator on ts() and x because I need object to access them , however , ios_base is a class and I still don't understand why it would need scope resolution operator to acces in and out , why cannot it access in and out with an object of ios_base?

Comment: @zLeon: It can. But what object of `ios_base` do you propose creating? And why? You're missing that these are _static_ members of `std::ios_base`.

Answer (score 1):

`ios_base` refers to a class, specifically `std::ios_base` (see C++11 27.5.3 [ios.base] in the standard). `ios_base::in` is defined to be a `static constexpr` variable of type `fmtflags`.

Thus, `ios_base::in` and `ios_base::out` and friends merely name constant variables.

e.g.:

```
class ios_base
{
    public:
    static constexpr fmtflags out = 1234 /* (or any other constant) */;
};

int main()
{
    // Access static member `out` of class `ios_base`
    printf("%d", ios_base::out);
}
```